# How to use pagination in Reactjs application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, pagination, blogs

I am implementing pagination for my blog page by using [react-js-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-pagination).

1. I am unable to fix this `pagination ui` and its content per page
2. Bind my data accordingly per page

I have tried to import `less` from `bootstrap` but it is not rendering for this.

Any suggestion on this to solve this pagination issue?

**Updated** code: it is working now
//blog.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Card, Grid, Cell, Dialog, CardMenu, Button, CardTitle, 
    CardText, CardActions, FABButton, Icon} from'react-mdl';
import { Container} from 'reactstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getBlog, deleteBlog } from '../../actions/resumeActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Loading from './Loading';
import Moment from 'moment';
import BlogModal from "./BlogModal";
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";

class Blogs extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                modal: false,
                justClicked: null,
                activePage: 1
            };
        
            this.handleOpenDialog = this.handleOpenDialog.bind(this);
            this.handleCloseDialog = this.handleCloseDialog.bind(this);
        }
    
    static propTypes = {
        getContact: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        deleteContact: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        resume: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        loading: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    toggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal
        });
    }

    handleOpenDialog(id) {
        this.setState({
          openDialog: true,
          justClicked: id
    
        });
    }
    
    handleCloseDialog() {
    this.setState({
        openDialog: false
    });
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getBlog();
    }

    onDeleteBlogClick = (id) => {
        this.props.deleteBlog(id);
    };

    handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
        console.log(`active page is ${pageNumber}`);
        this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
      }

  cardDialog(blogs, user){
    return(
        <Grid style={{padding: 0, display: 'contents'}}>
            
            {blogs.map(({ _id, blog_name, blog_desc, blog_image_link, blog_by }) => (
            <Cell col={12}>
                <Dialog open={this.state.openDialog && this.state.justClicked === _id} className="open-dialog">
                
                    <CardTitle style={{color: '#fff', height: '176px', backgroundImage: `url(${blog_image_link})`, backgroundPosition: 'center',
                    backgroundSize: 'cover',
                    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}>{blog_name}</CardTitle>
                    <CardText>
                        {blog_desc}
                    </CardText>
                    <CardActions border>
                       <p style={{float:'right', fontWeight:'bold'}}>Author: {blog_by}</p>
                    </CardActions>
                    <CardMenu style={{color: '#fff'}}>
                        <FABButton onClick={this.handleCloseDialog} className="close-button" >
                            <Icon name="close" />
                        </FABButton>
                    </CardMenu>
                </Dialog>
            </Cell>
            ))}
        </Grid>
    )
    
  }



    render(){
        const { blogs, loading} = this.props.resume;
        const { isAuthenticated, user } = this.props.auth;
        const itemsPerPage = 1; 
        let activeBlogs = blogs.slice (itemsPerPage * this.state.activePage - itemsPerPage, itemsPerPage * this.state.activePage)
        return(
            <Container>
             
            {loading ? (
            <div><Loading/></div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    {/* blog modal */}
                    <BlogModal />

                    {/* card dialog */}
                    {this.cardDialog(blogs, user)}

                    <Grid style={{padding: 0}} id="todo">
                        {activeBlogs.map(({ _id, blog_name, blog_by, date }) => (
                            <Cell key={_id} data-id={_id}>   
                            { this.props.isAuthenticated && (user.is_admin === true) ? 
                                <Button className="remove-btn"
                                color="danger"
                                size="sm"
                                onClick= {this.onDeleteBlogClick.bind(this, _id)}>
                                    &times;
                                </Button> : null }
                                <Card shadow={5} className="cards-grid">
                                    <CardTitle className="card-title-image"></CardTitle>
                                    <CardText>
                                        <b>{blog_name}</b>
                                    </CardText>
                                    
                                    <CardActions border>
                                        <Button className="blog-read-me-button" onClick={this.handleOpenDialog.bind(this, _id)}>Read </Button>
                                        <p style={{ fontStyle:'italic', fontWeight:'bold'}}>By-{blog_by} <span style={{float:'right',}}>{Moment(date).format('Do MMMM YYYY')}</span></p> 
                                    </CardActions>
                                </Card>  
                            </Cell>  
                        ))} 
                    </Grid>
                </div> 
                )}
                <Pagination
                activePage={this.state.activePage}
                itemsCountPerPage={1}
                totalItemsCount={2}
                pageRangeDisplayed={1}
                onChange={this.handlePageChange.bind(this)}
                itemClass='page-item'
                linkClass='page-link'
/>
            </Container>
        ) 
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    resume: state.resume,
    isAuthenticated : state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    auth: state.auth,
    loading: state.apiCallsInProgress > 0
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getBlog, deleteBlog }) (Blogs);
```

//current ui
[image: After making changes]

[image: redux]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default style of react-js-pagination. You have to style it yourself. However as far as I see, you are using bootstrap in your application, so you could use their styles in the following way:

```
<Pagination
                activePage={this.state.activePage}
                itemsCountPerPage={1}
                totalItemsCount={2}
                pageRangeDisplayed={1}
                onChange={this.handlePageChange.bind(this)}
                itemClass='page-item'
                linkClass='page-link'
/>
```

Comment: Hi Enchew, thanks for your time. i want to bind my data here as well. How can i implement that.

Comment: The pagination component is used just to visualize pages and give you the ability to access the page number. The logic that replaces the data with the data from the new page must be implemented by you.

Comment: any help on that to implement it.

Comment: Data has been stored in Redux and can be accessible .

Comment: Try adding the following code in cardDialog function: `    const itemsPerPage = 1;
    let activeBlogs = blogs.slice (itemsPerPage * this.state.activePage - itemsPerPage, itemsPerPage * this.state.activePage - 1)` . This will filter only the blog posts that you need. After that use this new collection when using the .map() function. Test it and if needed calibrate the formula, because I wrote it without the ability to test it. Let me know what is the result

Comment: Isn't it sould be in render(). As cardDialog() is for opening the modal?

Comment: Oh, yes, that's right. I thought you were calling this function in the render() function. In the meanwhile, if my answer fixed your styles issues, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212028/discussion-between-tanmoy-sarkar-and-enchew).