# how to add pagination and fire row click event in table in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have below  child component in react which I am rendering on button click event in parent component. Till here I have no problem. Table is getting rendered on page. I have written row click event findDetails() on table. But problem is that rowClick event in not working on row click. Instead of that it get executed when component is rendering on page. I want to execute on rowClick. Below is my code for table component. Also I need to implement pagination as well in same table which I am not sure how to do it.

```
class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  getHeaader = () => {
       var tableHeadings = [
      "Customer ID",
      "Customer Name",
      "Address",
      "Contact",
    ];
    return tableHeadings.map((key) => {
      return <th key={key}> {key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
    });
  };

  getRowsData = (e) => {
    return this.props.Data.map((value, index) => {
      const {
         "Customer_ID",
         "Customer_Name",
         "Address",
         "Contact",
      } = value;
      return (
        <tr
          key={CUSTOMER_ID}
          onClick={this.findDetails(value)}
        >
          <td> {CUSTOMER_ID} </td>
          <td> {CUSTOMER_NAME} </td>
          <td> {Address} </td>
          <td> {Contact} </td>
          <td>
            <button className="btn btn-info">Find Details</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };


  findDetails = (value) => {
    console.log("in show button", value.count);
    if (value["count"] === 0) {
      alert("No details for given customer");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table
          id="display-table"
          className="table table-bordered table table-hover table table-responsive pagination"
          style={{ tableLayout: "fixed" }}
        >
          <tbody>
            <tr>{this.getHeaader()}</tr>
            {this.getRowsData()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
`
```

Comment: `<tr>` is just a wrapping tag in HTML and does not accept onClick events. Instead try applying your onClick function on `<td>` tags.

Comment: @Enchew I have tried that as well but no luck. Its still behave the same way.

Comment: Actually what I said is gibberish and incorrect. I tested it and it worked. I found your mistake, please check the answer I wrote.

Comment: Can you please help in for how will I navigate to new component on button click.  I have written below line in findDetails() function, this.props.history.push("/NewComponent");

Comment: You could use `<Link to='/NewComponent> Find Details </Link>` Your way is possible too.

Comment: @Enchew you are champ mate :). Thanks a lot lot again.

Comment: Thank you, you are welcome. Please mark my answer as accepted, by clicking the tick icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke your onClick in the wrong way. When passing parameters, you have to wrap your function in an anonymous one:

```
  <tr
          key={CUSTOMER_ID}
          onClick={() => this.findDetails(value)}
  >
```

I'll explain. When passing `onClick`, React is waiting for a function name (actually a reference), that then it calls, by adding parentheses. If you add them by yourself as you did (`onClick={this.findDetails()`} ) you invoke the function right away and you pass the **RESULT** of the function to the `onClick` listener.

Comment: ohh my goodness!!!. I spent whole evening to fix this and you caught this is seconds. Thanks a lot for help. Could you also please help me how will I apply a pagination for this table.

Comment: Recently I helped someone in the site implementing pagination. Have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61311155/how-to-use-pagination-in-reactjs-application/61311285#61311285 Check my answer and the comments below the answer, which continue in the chat. In the meanwhile, please consider upvoting and marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: I will check. Thank you once again.